# Should [tag:dynamic-dns] and [tag:ddns] be merged?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Should [dynamic-dns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-dns) and [ddns](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/ddns) be merged?

I see a few questions that are tagged with both, and from the descriptions it's not clear what differences, if any, exist between them.

Comment: There's also [dyndns] as a synonym for [dynamic-dns].  Since there's already a lot of usage, synonomizing might be less disruptive than merging.

Comment: I'd be careful of any merges or synonyms; especially the one @fixer1234 suggests. "DynDNS" appears to refer to a specific brand/service rather than the concept of dynamic DNS updates as a whole.

Comment: @Bob, it's already a synonym and the wiki describes it as a synonym.

Comment: Yes[.](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/dynamic-dns)

Comment: I will vote for synonymizing [tag:dynamic-dns] and [tag:ddns]. Also, I suggest to synonymize [tag:dyndns], too, as there shouldn't be confusion with _DynDNS_ service anymore. They are called [Dyn's DNS](http://dyn.com/dns) now.